# Why I got this Syntax error of with statement, but i'm not actually using any?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I'm not using any 'with statement', but when I set the breakpoint, it gives me the error:

`SyntaxError: 'with' statements are not valid in strict mode`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function addItem() {
        var orderListElement, newLi, childCount;
        orderListElement = document.getElementById('orderList');
        newLi = document.createElement('li');
        childCount = orderListElement.children.length;
        newLi.textContent = 'new item ';
        orderListElement.appendChild(newLi);
    }
    function deleteItem() {
        var orderListElement, lastLi;
        orderListElement = document.getElementById('orderList');
        lastLi = orderListElement.lastChild;
        orderListElement.removeChild(lastLi);
    }
    function registHandler() {
        var addItemButton, deleteItemButton;
        addItemButton = document.getElementById('addItem');
        deleteItemButton = document.getElementById('deleteItem');
        addItemButton.addEventListener('click', addItem, false);
        deleteItemButton.addEventListener('click', deleteItem, false);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', registHandler, false);
}());
```

That's so annoying.

Comment: I'm not getting an error in Chrome, http://jsfiddle.net/Fe5CZ/.

Comment: BTW I'm using safari 6.0

Comment: No issues in Safari 5 on OS X Lion.

Comment: @Mat Yes there's no issue in Chrome and Safari 5

Comment: Is there any other JavaScript code on the page? Are you cached with an old version of a file?

Comment: @epascarello `yntaxError: 'with' statements are not valid in strict mode
line: 343
message: "'with' statements are not valid in strict mode"
stack: "evaluate@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵↵_evaluateAndWrap↵↵evaluateOnCallFrame↵↵[native code]"
__proto__: Error` That's the error I got, you might right because my code don't have 343 line. And I've refreshed the page, so I should not have cached version

Comment: refreshing page does not guarantee that you have uncached files.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue with Safari: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65829

To reproduce the Error, you simply need to type *any* code into the console while stopped at a breakpoint and while in strict mode.

Here's the code from the bug report:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    debugger;
})();
```

So when you're at the breakpoint, go to the console and type `2+3` (or any expression), and you'll get the Error.

[image]